# Is there a way to let run flash-app only on my page(domain), not local and not on other domain?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, dns, local

I created some game and would like to let the users play it only on my domain, so to forbid to play it offline or put on some other site. Is there a way to do it? Somehow check domain or so?

Answer (score 1):

Although it's hard to definitively control the distribution of your Flash content, there are a few different routes you can go down to, at least, make it harder to publish your content somewhere else.

One way is to check what url are loading the swf object is to check `loaderInfo.loaderURL` from the [LoaderInfo class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html).

```
var url:String = loaderInfo.loaderURL;
```

You can also check the loading url by using JavaScript through the [ExternalInterface class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html):

```
var url:String;
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    url = ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href");
}
```

Then check the url to see that it resides within your desired domain, like this:

```
if(!/^https?:\/\/www\.example\.com/.test(url)) {
    //This seems to be outside of your domain
}
```

You can find some additional information about this approach in this article:
http://www.ghostwire.com/blog/archives/as3-domain-locking-swfs/

---

Another approach is to try to download a file from a domain you control, this is especially effective if you are already downloading external assets to your swf.

By specifying an absolute url to the asset, like `http://www.example.com/assets/myExternalAsset.xml`, instead of a relative one, like `/assets/myExternalAsset.xml`, you can set up a [cross-domain-policy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e08.html) to determine what domains are able to access the content.

If the content is accessed from outside of your allowed domain(s), a security error event will be triggered and the download will not complete.

---

Having said this, I'm not fully sure if any of the above methods will fully protect you if your content, for example, is embedded inside of an iframe element on another site.

Comment: hm. And what if a user disables JS in browser?